# .NET Detect which domain was used to access a server to return right certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, dns, ssl-certificate

I was requested to build a small server which supports SSL in .net which works well but I'm having trouble solving one issue. The server could be reached from multiple domain and also have multiple self signed certificates. But how do I know which certificate to serve to the client? Is there some way to know what domain a client used to connect to the server?

The client is also my own software which can be changed in case it's easier to add extra info in the client or something.

Edit: The problem I am talking about is called SNI (Server Name Indication) which is an extension of the TLS protocol and not supported in .net 4.5 as far as I can tell. Is there any way to use SNI in .net? 
To clearify my situation I maintain both the client and server and therefore changes to both ends can be made.

Comment: Yes, with third-party SSL/TLS library (such as our SecureBlackbox). You would need to use SSL/TLS functionality provided by the library, i.e. replace your existing TLS code with the library calls.